# Put request work not properly in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am going to make restful server with codeigniter.
I did download Rest_Controller.php and Format.php from github and placed in libraries folder them.
By the way, all request are not working properly put, post,delete etc.
I used postman tool.The output is always

```
{"":false}
```

Help me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygiS2.png)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
require(APPPATH.'/libraries/Rest_controller.php'); 

class Api extends REST_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('book_model');
    }

    function put_info()
    {
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT'){
            echo "this is put request\n";
            var_dump($this->input->input_stream());
        }
        else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
            echo "this is post request\n";
        else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'DELETE')
            echo "this is delete request\n";
        return;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: rest put function]

Check the position of your put verb. Its should come at the end of function name.

Make sure you have passed valid access token in header like 
Authorization Bearer [access token]

Make sure your scopes are correct

[image: here is the postman view]

It should work perfectly.

Comment: Just add a new funtion let say info_put() it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Following method can be added to helpers, from there you can parse put request in any of the controller:

```
function parsePutRequest()
    {
        // Fetch content and determine boundary
        $raw_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $boundary = substr($raw_data, 0, strpos($raw_data, "\r\n"));

    // Fetch each part
    $parts = array_slice(explode($boundary, $raw_data), 1);
    $data = array();

    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        // If this is the last part, break
        if ($part == "--\r\n") break; 

        // Separate content from headers
        $part = ltrim($part, "\r\n");
        list($raw_headers, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $part, 2);

        // Parse the headers list
        $raw_headers = explode("\r\n", $raw_headers);
        $headers = array();
        foreach ($raw_headers as $header) {
            list($name, $value) = explode(':', $header);
            $headers[strtolower($name)] = ltrim($value, ' '); 
        } 

        // Parse the Content-Disposition to get the field name, etc.
        if (isset($headers['content-disposition'])) {
            $filename = null;
            preg_match(
                '/^(.+); *name="([^"]+)"(; *filename="([^"]+)")?/', 
                $headers['content-disposition'], 
                $matches
            );
            list(, $type, $name) = $matches;
            isset($matches[4]) and $filename = $matches[4]; 

            // handle your fields here
            switch ($name) {
                // this is a file upload
                case 'userfile':
                    file_put_contents($filename, $body);
                    break;

                // default for all other files is to populate $data
                default: 
                    $data[$name] = substr($body, 0, strlen($body) - 2);
                    break;
            } 
        }

    }
    return $data;
}
```